# What is the best way of storing history of only one object in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store history of one object and I'm looking for advice.

My "Owner" object has got following variables and arraylist:

```
private String name;
private int totalAmount;
private List<Payment> listOfPayments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I have to store history of this object (when Clients will pay to me, totalAmount will be increase, and Payments objects will be adding to listOfPayments).

And now I don't know what is the best way of storing history of objects like this.

In SQLite I want to store data like:

**dateState** (unique value, state of totalAmount and content of listOfPayments for some date e.g. in date 13.02.2017 totalAmount = 450, listOfPayments = [{...}, {...}] in another date 02.02.2017 total amount=500, listOfPayments = [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]

**totalAmount** - amount that I have for some day

**listOfPayments** - list of payments that was saved from very beggining to dateState

and storing in every row data like "name" or other that doesn't change is very memory wasting.

Where and how would you store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data is properly normalized, lists go into a separate table.

You need a table to store the owner's properties:

```
Owner
-------
OwnerID
name
```

The total amount does not need to be stored; it can be computed from the other data.

Each payment entry belongs to an owner, so it needs a foreign key:

```
Payment
---------
PaymentID
OwnerID
date
amount
...
```